# Is there a difference between Single.just(...) and Observable.just(...) in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

This might be a silly question, but I am relatively unfamiliar with using RxSwift - so I wanted to do a sanity check.

Is there any pragmatic difference between these two method definitions? Or are they basically identical?

```
func foo() -> Single<Bool> {
    return Single<Bool>.create { single in
        single(.success(true))
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}

func bar() -> Observable<Bool> {
    return Observable.just(true)
}
```

Any differences between thread execution order or memory management that I should be aware of?

I'm just looking for any "gotchas" that I might not have otherwise known about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the promise you are making to the caller. If you return a `Single`, you are saying that you are getting exactly one value.  I don’t need to look at the implementation to see that and I am guaranteed that this will always be the case.

In the `Observable` case, I am not guaranteed that more values aren’t coming.  Even if I look at the implementation and see it’s just a `just`, that doesn’t mean the code won’t change.

Comment: But execution wise, does RxSwift treat/schedule Singles and Observables any differently?

Comment: They are the same with regards to scheduling. It’s mostly about the type-safety of the contract being enforced.

Answer (score 4):

The `Single.just(_:)` operator calls `Observable.just(_:)` internally.

The Single type is a PrimitiveSequence type which is a wrapper around a standard Observable. This wrapper provides operators that ensure that a completed event is pushed immediately after a next event and it doesn't allow you to subscribe to onCompleted events. Specifically, when it comes to `just(_:)` there is little difference. The Single type adds a function to the call stack and a bit of extra memory which is used to ensure exactly one next event is emitted. That assurance does nothing in the context of a `just` though which will only ever emit a single element anyway.

As @LouFranco mentions in his answer and I say above, the contract of Single is different, but the type does *not* provide any compile time guarantees. You can still call `asSingle()` on a normal Observable, push out a completed event without a next event, or push out two next events, and the code will compile just fine but produce a runtime error. Since the type doesn't provide a guarantee against a runtime error, IMO it doesn't provide enough value to warrant its use. YMMV.